# How to make a zod type of string but with possible static values

Tags: typescript, zod

I need to make a property accept a predefined set of string literals, but it can also accept any string values.

This is how I did it in typescript

```
const PREDEFINED_VALUES = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] as const;

type TStaticValues = typeof PREDEFINED_VALUES[number]
type Values = (string & Record<string, unknown>) | TStaticValues;
```

With this, I can benefit from intellisense of predefined values to check for. I tried to do it in `zod` with the following:

```
const type = z.object({
  // some other types
  stringWithPredefinedValues: z.union([
    z.string().and(z.object({})),
    z.enum(PREDEFINED_VALUES)
  ])
})
```

But when I try to check for predefined values, it shows a ts error.

```
const testValue: string = 'any string should be accepted, but predefined values get detected.';

const check = PREDEFINED_VALUES.includes(testValue)
// ts error: Type 'string & {}' is not assignable to type '"value1" | "value2" | "value3"'.
```

I am uncertain if my `zod` object is correct, or if there is some sort of limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close to the solution. The missing part was re-assigning the array's type to be closer to `string[]`. Enum arrays are restricted in terms of array operations whenever they invoke generic functions.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygPAFQHxQLxQVCAPYEB2AJgM5THABOAlvgOZQD8GUAPmZTfQGRQDeAvlABcUfBABuECgG4AsACgFAYwD2+clAAKAJQCiAEV0AxAJIA5AwH0AagEEAMgFVdMNFADaAcnEBDADYArhAAjJ4ANFDe-kEATOGRvoEQAMyeALpQPqSq6sBy8jkajjC2AEL2upa22tq2AJoiFBA+hGp+ILBwoJAqAGZaeoamFvo2Ds4w7vgBALYARlJpSO4Z6DoGxuZWdk4u+cpqGnjk1tEQIuTUdG6ePvgdl5xkABYqAX6EUAuZSkoQYHhCBE5gFgFAwE1CBBejQIJ9EkFSLQIGCoXglICAHSefYFQ5gpTPCBKADWbmKZQqVRq9UxNCUgShxAAFMdgKckgBKfKFAlE0kxcklcqVaq1Op0-AMgJM5kAIjl3KAA)

```
type S<T> = T extends string ? T | string & {} : never;

const PREDEFINED_VALUES = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] as const;

// This is what you want
const USABLE_ARRAY: readonly S<typeof PREDEFINED_VALUES[number]>[] = PREDEFINED_VALUES;

const testValue: string = 'any string should be accepted, but predefined values get detected.';

const check = USABLE_ARRAY.includes(testValue);
const check2 = USABLE_ARRAY.includes("");
```

And intellisense works:

[image]

As a sidenote, `zod` will never give you types which you can't easily write by hand.

Comment: Your solution worked. I gave up and just used `ts-ignore`-d it because I found this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255 on github. Thanks